# using TimeSpan.ParseExact() method to parse string to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

I want to parse the string to time according to my custom culture.
I have the format as ShortTimePattern as HH:ss

example code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("en");
    c.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:ss";
    TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.ParseExact("07:55", "t", c, TimeSpanStyles.None);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.Read();

    //result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(ConvertToString(value, culture), "t", culture);
}
```

But now the problem is that i get

```
hours = 07
minutes = 55
seconds = 00
```

where as i want

```
hours = 07
minutes = 00
seconds = 55
```

as specified the format in the culture

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN ([TimeSpan.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider, TimeSpanStyles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782365%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

> The "`c`", "`t`", and "`T`" standard format strings use the formatting conventions of the invariant culture.

that's why you're getting that kind of output.

Why don't you do following:

```
TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.ParseExact("07:55", "hh':'ss", null);
```

Comment: Except you'd want `HH':'ss` as you need to quote colons in TimeSpan patterns.

Comment: i get format exception for both of these:                            TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.ParseExact("07':'55", "HH':'ss", null);                               TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.ParseExact("07':'55", "HH:ss", null);

Comment: Sorry, I put `''` in wrong string. Updated my question, try it now.

Comment: still an exception @MarcinJuraszek

Comment: OK, has to be `hh`, not `HH`.

Comment: thanks for answer. But isnt there anyway that i can do this with ShortTimeFormat in the culture?                                                      For me the culture is actually specified by the user.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46402/discussion-between-nomesh-gajare-and-marcinjuraszek)